# C code error: expected ';', identifier or '(' before 'char'. I can't seem to find the solution to this error. Can someone please help me out here?

Tags: c

```
void record_sale()
{
    struct record_sale
    {
        char customername[25];
        char item[20];
        double price;
        double payment;

    }

    /*Declaring variables*/
    char customername[25];
    char item[20];
    double payment,price,Sales;
    int userChoice = 0;
    char sales[15];
```

Answer (score 3):

You need a `;` just after the definition of the structure `record_sale`.

```
struct record_sale
{
    char customername[25];
    char item[20];
    double price;
    double payment;
}; //here
```

Comment: But when I do that a bunch of warnings showed up and they are saying 'unused variable'

Comment: Would you rather have code that does not compile at all or code that compiles with warnings you can either ignore or fix?  If you have unused variable warnings then use the variables or remove them since you don't need them.

Comment: @LeandreDyer , Because you don't use the variables. Ignore those warnings. It will disappear when you use all the variables.